# Prove that $\cos(x^2)$ is analytic at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I can't figure out how to go about showing any of the properties required for analytic with such a messy derivative. This is for my real analysis class and I just want to see for this example so that I can better understand it for the remaining.

Comment: Use the fact that the composition of analytic functions is analytic.

Answer (score 3):

Because $$\cos x^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{x^{4n}}{2n!} , |x|  <1$$

Comment: I don't think the condition $|x|<1$ is necessary.